# Create text file, print cell values in text file and upload to FTP server?

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I am using the following code to try and create a .txt file and upload it to my FTP server. I want to create a text file called `Ref.txt` and insert some cell values into the text file and then upload this to my FTP server. For some reason I do not get any errors but the text file doesn't get uploaded to my FTP server.

Could someone please show me where I am going wrong?

I want to create a temporary text file called `Ref.txt` on the users `P:/` drive then print `irange("A1").value`.

```
Dim vPath As String
Dim vFile As String
Dim vFTPServ As String
Dim fNum As Long

vPath = "P:\"
vFile = Ref & ".txt"
vFTPServ = "********"

'Mounting file command for ftp.exe
fNum = FreeFile()
Open "P:\" & Ref & ".txt" For Output As #fNum
Print #1, "hewdenportal.co.uk" ' your login and password"
Print #1, "/public_html/ns_requests"  'change to dir on server
Print #1, "bin" ' bin or ascii file type to send
Print #1, "put " & vPath & "\" & vFile & " " & vFile ' upload local filename to server file
Print #1, "close" ' close connection
Print #1, "quit" ' Quit ftp program
Close

Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & Ref & ".txt" & vFTPServ, vbNormalNoFocus

SetAttr vPath & Ref & ".txt", vbNormal
Kill vPath & Ref & ".txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code `fNum` is the handle to your file so you should use that when printing and closing the file. In your code change `Print #1` to `Print #fNum`. 
Also change `Close` to `Close #fNum`.
In the line `Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & Ref & ".txt" & vFTPServ, vbNormalNoFocus` the `-s` parameter tells ftp to execute the contents of the file. So it looks like you are creating the file and then telling ftp to upload the file using the commands in the file?

If you want to write the value of a range to the file then `Print #fNum Workbooks("book_name.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet_name").Range("A1").Value` will do it. If you fully qualify the cell address in this way, you always know which workbook and worksheet you are using.